# How to locally store 2D Array Passed in Class Declaration

Tags: c++

I'm trying to locally store a 2D array in a private member variable but I'm not sure how to allocate the memory.

```
class Class1{
   public:
      Class1(string strings[][2], int size){
          for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
              this->strings[i][0] = strings[i][0];
              this->strings[i][1] = strings[i][1];
          }
      }
   private:
      string strings[][2];
}
```

I understand that the compiler doesn't know how to allocate the memory for the size of string but I'm not entirely sure how else to go about this, Thank you

Comment: `std::string` is an object, which means you can call `new` on it like anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do that would be :

```
class Class1 {
public:
    Class1(string strings[][2], int size) {
        this->strings = new string*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this->strings[i] = new string[2];
            this->strings[i][0] = strings[i][0];
            this->strings[i][1] = strings[i][1];
        }
    }
private:
    string** strings;
};
```